# $mdDialog stacked/nested dialogs, is it possible?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to open one `$mdDialog` on top of the other. If possible, have unlimited overlapping dialogs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It seems to me that it could be really annoying user experience if an unlimited number of dialog boxes started springing up...

Comment: @haakon319 Andrey wants to annoy the user :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, it is not possible right now to have multiple `$mdDialog`. Honestly I really need this feature and tried it to get it to work but no success so far. Lets hope they allow this feature in future releases. 
Although there is discussion [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/698), you can find something useful there.

### **NOTE: This is no longer the correct answer, as opposed to the time period it was answered, look below for more answers.**

Comment: I'm working on something that might serve as a solid add-on solution; I'll post it here when I'm done testing.

Comment: It is possible, here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ga027OYU5nrkua3JxNRy?p=preview

Comment: @GabrielAnzaldoAlvarado Great solution, you made my day :). I noticed there is `skipHide` parameter, where we can set `true` to prevent auto hide.

Comment: There is an enhancement to add multiple dialogs in v1.1.1. https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8630

Comment: @gabodev77 This is fabulous. Thank you. The key, as user2518430 has noticed, is the skipHide parameter which must be set on the *inner dialog*. If you make this a separate answer, it might benefit the question as a whole.

Comment: You should consider updating this answer as it's no longer accurate. Wrong answer's marked as correct are a dis-service to the community.

Comment: Just for those who bump in here and read accepted answer, As described by @holfz in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42250630/2828434) from angular 1.1.2, 'skipHide' does not work, instead 'multiple' works.

Answer (score 21):

UPDATE: As per @Magnus, it was updated to `multiple` as of v1.1.2

---

Add `skipHide: true` to the second dialog's options object.

This works for me: http://webiks.com/mddialog-with-a-confirmation-dialog/

Comment: Please put essential link contents. Resource can be unavailable in some point of time, while copypaste will stay here.

Comment: Please not the property name change from v1.1.2. See answer from @Dorival below. The property name is now `multiple`, not `skipHide`.

Answer (score 21):

Gabriel Anzaldo Alvarado gave the right answer in my opinion, the correct answer is shared in a [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ga027OYU5nrkua3JxNRy?p=preview). But as requested by many users, I'm adding the actual code in case the link becomes unavailable in the future.

Basically, while opening your dialog using the `.show({})` function, add the option `skipHide: true`.

**HTML**

```
<body>
 <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" 
    ng-cloak="" 
    class="virtualRepeatdemoVerticalUsage" 
    ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content layout="column">
    <md-button ng-click="ctrl.moreInfo(1)">
       Open Dialog
    </md-button>
  </md-content>
 </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])

  .controller('AppCtrl', function ($interval, $mdDialog) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.moreInfo = function moreInfo(thing) {
      $mdDialog.show({
        controllerAs : 'dialogCtrl',
        clickOutsideToClose : true,
        bindToController : true,
        controller : function ($mdDialog) {
          this.click = function click() {
            $mdDialog.show({
              controllerAs : 'dialogCtrl',
              controller : function ($mdDialog) {
                this.click = function () {
                  $mdDialog.hide();
                }
              },
              preserveScope : true,
              autoWrap : true,
              skipHide : true,
              template : '<md-dialog class="confirm"><md-content><md-button ng-click="dialogCtrl.click()">I am in a 2nd dialog!</md-button></md-content></md-dialog>'
            })
          }
        },
        autoWrap : false,
        template : '<md-dialog class="stickyDialog" data-type="{{::dialogCtrl.thing.title}}"><md-content><md-button ng-click="dialogCtrl.click()">I am in a dialog!</md-button></md-content></md-dialog>',
        locals : {
          thing : thing
        }
      })
    }
  });
})();
```

The code above worked for me.

As noted by Vincenzo in another answer, while stacking mdDialogs, the dialogs beneath will not grey-out, there is a CSS trick to solve that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38013682/366662

**UPDATE**

This answer works for version 1.1.1, from version 1.1.2 the Material team [changed the property](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10076) from `skipHide` to `multiple`. So, be careful when copy-pasting the snippet. Check your Material version and use the correct property accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for noting the property name change

Answer (score 7):

As Gabriel Anzaldo Alvarado wrote in the comment, it is possible as you can see on this Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ga027OYU5nrkua3JxNRy?p=preview

In addition, you can add some css classes to get the same background grey overlay:
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7262

```
._md-dialog-backdrop:nth-of-type(even) {
    z-index: 81;
}

._md-dialog-backdrop:nth-of-type(odd) {
    z-index: 79;
}

.md-dialog-container:nth-of-type(even) {
    z-index: 80;
}

.md-dialog-container:nth-of-type(odd) {
    z-index: 82;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

From Angular Material v1.1.2 the option *skipHide* has been replaced by *multiple*.

Comment: Thank you - surprisingly almost no one shows how to deal with layered backdrops.

Comment: The CSS part will not work consistently, as it is entirely dependent on the number of `div`s in your DOM. [`:nth-of-type` works on the type and not the class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type#CSS).

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/698) is a workaround to have nested dialogs.

The idea is when the second is open save the state of the first, and when the second is closed launch the first dialog again.

Comment: While this touches on how one might approach this problem, it does not provide guidance about how to implement a solution. =(

Comment: @RyanKimber Here is an example implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ga027OYU5nrkua3JxNRy?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

***skiphide*** has been deprecated. Use ***multiple*** key instead. See documentation [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)

here is a code snippet

```
myCtrl.demoClick = function moreInfo(thing) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controllerAs: 'dialogCtrl',
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            bindToController: true,
            controller: function ($mdDialog) {
                this.click = function click() {
                    $mdDialog.show({
                        preserveScope: true,
                        multiple: true,
                        controllerAs: 'dialogCtrl',
                        controller: function ($mdDialog) {
                            this.click = function () {
                                $mdDialog.hide();
                            }
                        },
                        template: '<md-dialog class="confirm"><md-content>I am in a 2nd dialog!<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="dialogCtrl.click()">Confirm!</md-button></md-content></md-dialog>'
                    })
                }
            },
            autoWrap: false,
            template: '<md-dialog class="stickyDialog" data-type="{{::dialogCtrl.thing.title}}"><md-content>I am in a dialog!<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="dialogCtrl.click()">Click me to do something</md-button></md-content></md-dialog>',
            locals: {
                thing: thing
            }
        })}
```

Answer (score 4):

From Angular Material version 1.1.2 an above: Use option *multiple*.

Use option *skipHide* for previous versions.

Example

```
$mdDialog.show({
    template: 'asdf'
    controller: "xyzController",
    multiple: true // Replace with "skipHide" on Angular Material 1.1.1 or before
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work with very little effort and a bit of angular hacking.

To make things clear, I'm using Angular v1.5.3 & Angular Material v1.0.6.

With previous versions if you add `skipHide: true` to your dialog definition object, it will allow multiple dialogs. Your issue then comes to the cancel button which will close the wrong dialog box.

The solution is rather calling `$mdDialog.cancel` we want to call `$mdDialog.hide` as it correctly resolves the right dialog box. Rather than making sure you have setup every instance correctly, or even making sure 3rd party libs also follow this pattern, we can decorate the `$mdDialogProvider`.

**$provide.decorator**

> ```
> $provide.decorator(name, decorator);
> ```
>
> Register a service decorator with the $injector. A service decorator intercepts the creation of a service, allowing it to override or modify the behavior of the service. The object returned by the decorator may be the original service, or a new service object which replaces or wraps and delegates to the original service.

```
angular.module('module').config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$mdDialog', function($delegate) {
        var methodHandle = $delegate.show;
        function decorateDialogShow() {
            var args = angular.extend({}, arguments[0], {
                skipHide: true
            });
            return methodHandle(args);
        }
        $delegate.show = decorateDialogShow;
        $delegate.cancel = function() {
            return $delegate.hide(null);
        }
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

The above will simply replace the cancel method, with the existing and working hide method. Also sets a global default so that skipHide is set initially on all dialog boxes.

Winner winner!

Answer (score 1):

```
 $mdDialog.show({
     parent: angular.element(document.body),
     templateUrl: 'template.html',
     clickOutsideToClose: true,
     fullscreen: true,
     preserveScope: true,
     autoWrap: true,
     skipHide: true,
     controllerAs: 'customDialog',
     controller: function ($mdDialog) {
        this.callNewDialog = function (dialogCallback) {
            dialogCallback();
        };
      }});
```

call in view:

```
ng-click="customDialog.callNewDialog(vm.addNewCustomer)"
```

and `vm.addNewCustomer` will be a function that open new dialog

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, just add "skipHide: true" where you calling mdDialog..
just like:

```js
$scope.xyz = function(anything) {
  $mdDialog.show({
    controller: "xyzController",
    skipHide: true,
    templateUrl: 'path-to-partial/xyzDialog.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    clickOutsideToClose: true
  })
}
```

Update: this is for angularJs (Angular 1)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use mdPanels. Little snippet:

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject){
         $mdPanel.open(Object.assign({
            hasBackdrop: true,
            zIndex: 85, //greater than modal and lower than autocomplete\select
            locals: Object.assign({
                onClose: resolve
            }, locals),
            template: getCommonTemplate(template, heading),
            bindToController:true,
            controller: 'PanelDummyController as $ctrl',
            panelClass: 'rl-modal-panel',
            position: $mdPanel.newPanelPosition()
                .absolute()
                .center()
        }))


 });


controller('PanelDummyController', function (mdPanelRef) {
    'ngInject';

    const close = () => mdPanelRef.close().then(() => {
        this.onClose(Object.assign({}, this));
    });

    this.$mdDialog = {
        cancel: close,
        hide: close
    };
});
```

and add little styling to class.
It's not fully copy of modal, but it's quite good implementation and could be improved to fully copy.

Answer (score 0):

in the latest AngularJs Material dialog, you can find this solution:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#multiple-dialogs

It uses multiple dialog preset or configuration.

Answer (score -3):

Absolutely not possible.* for now. It is understandable for some situations but other way is needed too.
So, I preferred to use custom popup dialogs variates for same functionalities.
Otherwise md-dialog gives pain to doing job.

- Yes I did that but if 3 nested needed then writing code ok but another one can not understand it.
  You can do the job by giving scope and preservescope parameters then manage when to close and which to open next ...brrrr...

Comment: 'Absolutely not possible.' many people were proven wrong after they say that. :)

Comment: Good for them. Is there any code example ? 
It would be wonderfull in my projects i used custom angular modals and collegues are more happy thats all.
thnks.

Comment: Search for Gabriel Anzaldo Alvarado on this page and you shall find the link.

Comment: Thank you very much. @Tymski. 
But i am still behind my answer.
regards

Comment: `skipHide: true` in the nested dialog will fix this... confirmed working for `1.0.9`.

Comment: [Absolutely not possible.* for now.] means in that date April 24... :)
Absolute word may be coused reaction... 
Doing somethink maynot be right way ...
anyway ...  thanks